# Radius of convergence work check

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

**Original question**
Find radius of convergence of the Maclaurin series for $f(x)=(4-x)^{-0.5}$

**Attemp at solution**

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(2n)!(x^n)}{2^{4n}(n!)^2}$$

ratio test:

$$=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{4n}(n!)^2}{(2n)!x^n}\frac{(2n+2)!x^{n+1}}{2^{4n+4}((n+1)!)^2}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}|x|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{2^4(n+1)^2}$$
$$=|x|\times0$$

The answer is inconsistent with the other parts of the question and contradicts the answer key, where in this process is an error?

Comment: Perhaps your solution allows $x>4$, which is not allowed for the original function?

Comment: @SimpleArt: Are you saying that although the ratio test itself showed that any finite value of x is applicable but the original function restricts the radius of convergence anyways?

Comment: You should get radius of convergence $4$.  By the way, $\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(n+1)^2}$ has limit $4$, not $0$.

Comment: I'm suggesting that that might be the case.  I'm not to familiar with 'radius of convergence' to be honest, but it might seem to be that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors:

1) the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ in the front should have disappeared after you take ratios,

2) the limit of $\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{2^4 (n+1)^2}$ at $n \rightarrow \infty$ is not zero, since both the top and bottom are degree $2$. Use L'hopital's rule or compare the leading terms.